# How to replace menu attribute based on a multilevel menu

Tags: jquery

Hi I have this menu structure.

```
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/link">Item 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="/link">Sub 1.1</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/link">Sub 1.1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/link">Sub 1.1.2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/link">Sub 1.2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/link">Item 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/link">Sub 2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/link">Sub 2.2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/link">Item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
```

And I wish to convert some of the < a > tag's href to '#' like the following:

```
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Sub 1.1</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/link">Sub 1.1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/link">Sub 1.1.2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/link">Sub 1.2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/link">Sub 2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/link">Sub 2.2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/link">Item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
```

I am trying to use the following jquery to achieve but failed to, can some one help to figure out. thanks.

```
if ( $('ul li a').next().is('ul') ){

   $(this).attr('href','#');
}
```

My logic basically is **IF < a > next sibling is < ul > THEN replace this < a > 's attribute href with "#"** This way I am able to preserve the links for those that has no children or the last menu element of its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `filter` :

```
$('ul li a').filter(function(){
    return $(this).next('ul').length;
}).attr('href', '#');
```